# is it possible to get user profile data by scraping linkedIn without entering our login credentials?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm new to web scrapping, is it possible to get user profile data by scraping linkedIn without entering our login credentials?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

No i don't think that this is possible. You cannot bypass the authwall and when logged in, there's a pretty fair chance that they will ban your account.

https://www.reddit.com/r/scrapy/comments/gyyx3f/advice_scraping_linkedin_why_does_my_script_only/